# sql-server: rewriting this query to make values as columns

Tags: sql-server

The query below assigns a weight to each column GER1, 2, and 3. Adding to the number of times Growth, Efficiency, and Risk  occur. https://i.stack.imgur.com/QpVRr.png

How can I rewrite it to where it shows the same results but Growth, Efficency, and Risk are the column names with the `score` as its value. No need to show `rank`.

Desired output:

```
Growth    Efficiency   Risk

8            15          7
```

-

```
 declare @MainHospital varchar(50)='Hospital1';
                                   WITH cte AS (
                                   SELECT 2 score, GER1 area FROM Survey
                                   WHERE MainHospital = @MainHospital
                                   UNION ALL
                                   SELECT 1 score, GER2 area FROM Survey
                                   WHERE MainHospital = @MainHospital
                                   UNION ALL
                                   SELECT 0 score, GER3 area FROM Survey
                                   WHERE MainHospital = @MainHospital
                                   ), cte2 AS (
                                   SELECT area, SUM(score) score FROM cte
                                   GROUP BY area
                                   HAVING area IS NOT NULL


                                   ), cte3 AS (
                                   SELECT area, score, 
                                   RANK() OVER (ORDER BY score DESC) rank
                                   FROM cte2
                                   )
                                   SELECT rank, area, score
                                   FROM cte3
                                   ORDER BY rank;
```

Going off the provided answer, how can I condense this query

```
SELECT    
   SUM(CASE WHEN [GER1] = 'Growth' THEN 2 ELSE 0 END) as "Growth",
   SUM(CASE WHEN [GER1] = 'Efficiency' THEN 2 ELSE 0 END) as Efficiency,
   SUM(CASE WHEN [GER1] = 'Risk' THEN 2 ELSE 0 END) as Risk,

   SUM(CASE WHEN [GER2] = 'Growth' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as "Growth",
   SUM(CASE WHEN [GER2] = 'Efficiency' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Efficiency,
   SUM(CASE WHEN [GER2] = 'Risk' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Risk,

   SUM(CASE WHEN [GER3] = 'Growth' THEN 0 ELSE 0 END) as "Growth",
   SUM(CASE WHEN [GER3] = 'Efficiency' THEN 0 ELSE 0 END) as Efficiency,
   SUM(CASE WHEN [GER3] = 'Risk' THEN 0 ELSE 0 END) as Risk,


FROM Survey
WHERE MainHospital = @MainHospital
GROUP BY MainHospital;
```

Answer (score 1):

For a fixed number of columns, I would just use a case statement, something along these lines:

```
...
sum (case when area='Efficiency' then score else 0 end) as Efficiency,
...
```

You could look into pivoting, but I think this is a lot simpler.

EDIT:
I'm not sure that I completely understand everything.  But I don't think you need that many case statements. I think you can do something like this:

```
sum (case 
  when [GER1] = 'Growth' then 2
  when [GER2] = 'Growth' then 1
  when [GER3] = 'Growth' then 0  -- If it's really 0 you could just leave this one out
  else 0 
end) as "Growth"...
```

Comment: Makes sense but no idea how to go about it since I'm not adding a score to just Efficiency. its IF efficiency is in GER1 add 2 to it. Add 1 if it occurs in GER2

Comment: I added an example based on your explanation.